# Bourbaki's epsilon-calculus notation

Tags: metamathematics, bourbaki, notation, lo.logic, proof-theory

Bourbaki used a very very strange notation for the epsilon-calculus consisting of $\tau$s and $\blacksquare$.  In fact, that box should not be filled in, but for some reason, I can't produce a \Box.

Anyway, I was wondering if someone could explain to me what the linkages back to the tau mean, what the boxes mean.  Whenever I read that book, I replace the $\tau$s with Hilbert's $\varepsilon$s.  I mean, they went to an awful lot of trouble to use this notation, so it must mean something nontrivial, right?

You can [see](http://books.google.com/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&lpg=PP1&dq=bourbaki&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=&f=false) it on the first page of the google books link I've posted.  I'm not sure if it's supposed to be intentionally vague, but they never introduce any metamathematical rules to deal with linkages except for the criteria of substitution, which pretty much cannot interact with $\tau$ terms.

Also, of course, since it's a book written to be completely a pain in neck to read, they use a hilbert calculus, and even worse, without primitive equality for determining whether or not two assemblies are equivalent.

Comment: I've forced this question into wiki mode, because I'm afraid that it will be voted down for being about metamathematics rather than mathematics itself.

Comment: However, this is the first correct use of the tag `[metamathematics]`.  This is literally about symbols on ticker tapes and such.  

Comment: metamathematics is the mathematics of mathematics. It is a branch of mathematics that includes model theory, proof theory, etc. I don't understand your comment about being the only valid use of the 'metamathematics' tag. 

Comment: Well, ya see, there's "real" metamathematics, and "applied" metamathematics...   I hope someone catches that reference. 

Comment: In the sense of Hardy.

Comment: The tags "metamathematics", "bourbaki" and "notation" don't refer to any particular field of mathematics, which may explain why it took five months to get the accepted answer.  I added lo.logic and proof-theory, you might get more responses by deleting the first three tags and using set-theory, formal-proofs, zfc, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let me address the part of the question about "what the linkages back to the tau mean, what the boxes mean."  The usual notation for using Hilbert's epsilon symbol is that one writes $(\varepsilon x)\phi(x)$ to mean "some (unspecified) $x$ satisfying $\phi$ (if one exists, and an arbitrary object otherwise)."  If, like Bourbaki, one wants to avoid quantifiers in the official notation and use $\varepsilon$ instead (specifically, expressing $(\exists x)\phi(x)$ as $\phi((\varepsilon x)\phi(x))$), then any non-trivial formula will contain lots of $\varepsilon$'s, applied to lots of variables, all nested together in a complicated mess. To slightly reduce the complication, let me suppose that bound variables have been renamed so that each occurrence of $\varepsilon$ uses a different variable.  Bourbaki's notation (even more complicated, in my opinion) is what you would get if you do the following for each occurrence of $\varepsilon$ in the formula.  (1) Replace this $\varepsilon$ with $\tau$. (2) Erase the variable that comes right after the $\varepsilon$.  (3) Replace all subsequent occurrences of that variable with a box.  (4) Link each of those boxes to the $\tau$ you wrote in (1).  So $(\varepsilon x)\phi(x)$ becomes $\tau\phi(\square)$ with a link from the $\tau$ to the boxes (as many boxes as there were $x$'s in $\phi(x)$).

One might wonder why Bourbaki does all this.  As far as I know, the point of the boxes and links is that there are no bound variables in the official notation; they've all been replaced by boxes.  So Bourbaki doesn't need to define things like free and bound occurrences of a variable.  Where I (and just about everybody else) would say that a variable occurs free in a formula, Bourbaki can simply say the variable occurs in the formula.

I suspect that Bourbaki chose to use Hilbert's $\varepsilon$ operator as a clever way of getting the axiom of choice and the logical quantifiers all at once.  And I have no idea why they changed $\varepsilon$ to $\tau$ (although, while typing this answer, I noticed that I'd much rather type tau than varepsilon).

Comment: Adrian Mathias in "A term of length..." points out that $\epsilon$ "is visually too close to the sign $\in$ for the membership relation" and gives a hint to his Danish Lectures. To learn more about $\tau$, please read http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto.pdf ;-) 

Comment: I didn't notice this answer when you posted it.  I came back to this question because I was talking about it with someone, and this is fantastic.  I've chosen this as the new 'best answer'. Thanks!

Comment: While Bourbaki's solution looks weird to modern eyes, a treatment of bound variables require a surprising among of care to get right (try to reproduce capture-avoiding substitution from a book on lambda calculus).
Once you replace his links by deBrujin indexes (which I find sensible), what he does seems isomorphic to the idea behind the "locally nameless representation" of binding:
http://www.chargueraud.org/research/2009/ln/main.pdf

Comment: @Blaisorblade I believe that de Bruijn indices would be problematic, because they require integers and counting... which is defined later in the book.

Comment: @Mageek Interesting point, but I'm sure those "arrows" are defined even later than naturals. You need to take for granted _some_ amount of (very weak) maths to even define the syntax. The naturals for de Bruijn indexes aren't a big problem (you only need a fixed amount of naturals, that can be computed once you write the book, so you don't even need the axiom of infinity).

Comment: In general, most foundations assume some language like first-order logic (FOL), which needs either variables or deBruijn indexes to be written — either solution has "bootstrapping" problems with standard (but subtle) solutions — IIUC, you assume  you can use some (metalevel) FOL to do maths at all, you justify that it makes sense "outside of maths" (that's the job of logician), and you can also formalize FOL _inside_ math to show theorems about it.

Comment: @Blaisorblade I completely agree with you that "counting" or having a big enough ordered sequence of distinct symbols is necessary for any manipulation of mathematics. But in Bourbaki's book they don't speak about that. The arrows are defined in the first pages. But I feel that it is disingenuous because verifying a proof manually, and manipulating these arrows, is of course impossible without a mental model of counting.

Comment: You seem to demand to use fully formalized maths to define what maths is; I'm sure I've also wondered about, but that's not what happens. I'm sorry I can't point to a good answer on that; this is likely covered when discussing foundations of maths.

My comment wasn't about how to define things while bootstrapping maths; once you've done the bootstrapping, you could likely show (a copy of) Bourbaki's definition (which, as I said, is unusual) is equivalent to using de Bruijn indexes. I suppose you could nowadays use de Bruijn indexes in the foundations, but I'm no expert there.

Answer (score 24):

You must read the charming essay lampooning this notation, while also giving a thorough logical analysis of it, by [Adrian Mathias](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/).

- Adrian Mathias, [A Term of Length 4,523,659,424,929](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/inefff.pdf), Synthese 133 (2002) 75--86

He describes it thus:

> A calculation of the number of symbols required to give Bourbaki's definition of the number 1; to which must be added 1,179,618,517,981 disambiguatory links. The implications for Bourbaki's philosophical claims and the mental health of their readers are discussed.

Comment: Brilliant!  Great Job!

Comment: I knew it! Those first few sections are pretty much unreadable.

Comment: I still like that formalism though.  Even though it's totally unusable.  I really like that $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Adrian taught me set theory! I don't think he ever forgave Bourbaki for eschewing the axiom(-scheme) of replacement. He seems to have been having little swipes at them ever since :-)

Comment: Adrian is great, I agree. But this article is more than a little swipe---it makes them look completely ridiciulous about math logic. He has another article called "The ignorance of Bourbaki", if you follow the link on his name, which is directly critical of this particular Bourbaki volume, as well as some follow-up articles.

Comment: Those are some impressive articles.  I had no idea Bourbaki was so set on pretending Godel's work didn't exist.

Comment: Here's a PDF link for those of us who don't have easy access to a DVI reader: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/inefff.pdf

Comment: @S.Carnahan: I hear that's quite contentious (or wrong). http://math.stackexchange.com/a/929385/79293

Comment: Using complexity theory, the core of Mathias essay is just that "Translating an existential ∃x. ϕ(x) to ϕ(εx. ϕ(x)) using Hilbert's ε operator introduces copies of ϕ; repeating this for more quantifiers produces an exponential blowup of the formula." It'd have helped if he actually wrote this anywhere. And after you show an exponential blowup, actually computing examples feels a bit silly.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Thank you for the link.  I don't think Bourbaki's acknowledgement of incompleteness constitutes much of a rebuttal of Mathias's point, since the argument was that Gødel's work did not yield a substantial change in Bourbaki's philosophy toward formalization of mathematics.  Mathias seems to draw his evidence not from the set theory text, but from contemporary articles by members of the group.

Comment: A more detailed account by Mathias was published in 2014 and could be mentioned here.

Comment: (Please do mention it, @katz, and consider editing that information into the answer.) I'm just rereading this thread now. It *is* a well-done essay, although I wouldn't call it "charming" -- it looks like Mathias is taking maybe a little too much delight rubbing Bourbaki's face in it. It elicits in me a slight counter-reaction: could it be said that Bourbaki's foundations is nevertheless humanly comprehensible? Any piece of real mathematics will seem incomprehensible once all cuts have been eliminated and everything is in machine language, but humans can still handle towers of recursiveness.

Comment: Probably @MikhailKatz's reference is to [Hilbert, Bourbaki, and the scorning of logic](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/logbanfinalmk.pdf) ([MSN](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3205073)).

Answer (score 14):

Matthias' polemics are funny at points but also misleading in several respects:

1. ZFC also has enormous length and depth of deductions for trivial material. According to Norman Megill's metamath page, "complete proof of 2 + 2 = 4 involves 2,452 subtheorems including the 150 [depth of the proof tree] above. ... These have a total of 25,933 steps — this is how many steps you would have to examine if you wanted to verify the proof by hand in complete detail all the way back to the axioms."  Megill's system is based on a formalism for substitutions so there may be an enormous savings here compared to the way in which Matthias performs the counts (i.e., the full expanded size in symbols) for Bourbaki's system.  If I correctly recall other information from Megill about the proof length he estimated for various results in ZFC, the number of symbols required can be orders of magnitude larger and this is what should be compared to Matthias' numbers.
2. The proof sizes are enormously implementation dependent. Bourbaki proof length could be a matter of inessential design decisions.  Matthias claims at the end of the article that there is a problem using Hilbert epsilon-notation for incomplete or undecidable systems, but he gives no indication that this or any other problem is insurmountable in the Bourbaki approach.
3. Indeed, Matthias himself appears to have surmounted the problem in his other papers, by expressing Bourbaki set theory as a subsystem of ZFC.  So either he has demonstrated that some reasonably powerful subsystems of ZFC have proofs and definitions that get radically shorter upon adding Replacement, or that the enormous "term" he attributes to the *Theorie des Ensembles* shrinks to a more ZFC-like size when implemented in a different framework.

EDIT. A search for Norman Megill's calculations of proof lengths in ZFC found the following:

"even trivial proofs require an
astonishing number of steps *directly from axioms*.  Existence of the
empty set can be proved with 11,225,997 steps and transfinite recursion
can be proved with 11,777,866,897,976 steps."

and

"The proofs exist only in principle, of course, but their
lengths were backcomputed from what would result from more traditional
proofs were they fully expanded. .....  In the current version of my proof
database which has been reorganized somewhat, the numbers are:

empty set = 6,175,677 steps

transf. rec. = 24,326,750,185,446 steps"

That's only the number of steps.  The number of symbols would be much, much higher.

Comment: Why does it take so many steps to prove the empty set exists? If $B$ is any set, then the Comprehension axiom says {$x\in B | x \neq x$} exists, and this is empty. I understand that a formal version of this argument would be longer, filling in all the logical steps, but what are most of those 6 million steps in Megils' proof about?

Comment: I don't know, but both Megill's and Matthias' numbers seem to indicate that when you deliberately strip away the higher-level interface that we implicitly use to handle the (also implicit, or unspecified) lower-level proof language, things balloon.

Comment: Also, Megill's work is downloadable from his Metamath (Proof Explorer) web site. 

Comment: On a blank piece of paper, I wrote out a formal proof in
ZFC of the assertion that the empty set exists $\exists
B\forall y\, y\notin B$, in full exquisite detail. It fit
on half a page, and had exactly 10 steps. I'll put the outline in the next comment. 

Comment: The outline is:
Separation Axiom instance $\forall A\exists B\forall z(z\in
B\iff z\in A\wedge \neg z= z)$. Universal instantiation
strips off A quantifier. Existential instantiation produces
$\forall z(z\in B\iff z\in A\wedge \neg z=z)$. State a
tautology and apply MP to get $\forall z(z=z\to z\notin
B)$. Equality axiom $\forall z\, z=z$. Another tautology and
MPs give $\forall z\, z\notin B$. Existential generalization
yields $\exists B\forall z\, z\notin B$, as desired.

Comment: Another issue is that Mathias was computing the size of the term defining
$1$, not the proof that it exists (or that it is the
multiplicative identity). So the relevant comparison would
be the fact that in ZFC, the empty set is defined by the
formula $\forall z\, \neg z\notin x$,
which has 6 symbols. The natural number $1$ (usually taken
to be {0}) is defined by $\forall y\, (y\in x \iff \forall z\, \neg z\in y)$, which has 14 symbols.


Comment: Megill's program is a proof checker, so I assume he is counting something akin to the number of nodes in a parse tree for each sentence of the proof, and the number of comparisons of such nodes needed to see that, e.g., your first step *is* an instance of Separation.  Your much smaller counts are for the higher-level interface where a proof checker is in place to do this.  In similar fashion, Bourbaki only gives a (presumably short enough to fit on a page or several such) high level definition of "1" that unwinds at a lower level into Matthias' monstrosity. 

Comment: On the other hand, Megill's more modest (and more recent -- implementation dependence again) figure of 25000 steps and 2400 subtheorems for proving 2+2=4 does sound more like the number of lines in a Principia Mathematica-style development.  His material is downloadable and the proofs can be viewed online, so it should not be that hard to figure out what he has calculated. 

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins (A little late for a rebuttal, but...) The reason why the Metamath proof that the empty set exists is so long when fully expanded because it uses previous theorems which have more complex derivations but are more natural to use. A "handmade" direct proof from axioms would be much shorter, but not as short by the usual metric which allows for the use of previous theorems. I did a little trivial fiddling around with the null set proof and got the total count down to 211870, but doing predicate calculus without prop.calc. theorems is really painful so I didn't go all the way.

Comment: If you want small formal proofs, you need a natural deduction system with a cut rule, as explained by Boolos "Don't eliminate cut" — eliminating cut introduces an exponential blowup, because it replaces each use of a lemma with its proof. In Hilbert-style systems, using the deduction theorem does the same thing. Once you show exponential complexity, computing examples is silly.
The Curry-Howard isomorph of this problem is well-known to compiler writers: when you implement inlining of functions, you can't inline all functions or you will introduce exponential blowup.

Answer (score 6):

I would like just to mention about "what the linkages back to the tau mean, what the boxes mean", that this notation has been revisited by Nicolaas Govert de Bruijn in the framework of the lambda-calculus and is largely used in theoretical computer science as a very convenient tool and is known now as "de Bruijn" indices. A literature can be found about this.

Comment: Since Bourbaki uses names for free variables, he's using a variant of deBrujin indexes — we call it "locally nameless representation". See my comment to the other answer:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14356/bourbakis-epsilon-calculus-notation#comment558701_31787

Answer (score 1):

The notation using links was invented by Charles Saunders Peirce with his existential diagrams in 1883. It was reinvented by Willard van Orman Quine in his book Mathematical Logic in 1940. (Quine did not use the notation.) Bourbaki reinvented it in 1970.

I submit that the notation with links is more fundamental than de Bruijn indices because that still adds certain implementation details. The notation with links may seem awkward but for example in the theory of interpretations there are lots of artificial problems of keeping track of variable-names. These can be side-stepped using the links.

I think that the use of links dictates a co-inductive, top-down, `decompositional' view of syntax.

Comment: The statement about 1970 is not true. The link occurs in a draft by Bourbaki of around 1951 (E I.1 Etat 3). In His article _Foundations of mathematics for the working mathematician_ (J. Symbolic Logic 14), published in 1949, however, He uses a "surrounding line".

Comment: Link to the 1949 Bourbaki paper in JSL: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2268971. The 'surrounding line' line is near the bottom of page 3, where you can see a circle.